# ListView on Fragment does not appear

Tags: android

I have made a ListView on a Fragment.

```
 public class MyList extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, container, false);

    return view;
  }
}
```

This is the xml file where is the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout                                                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ddffff"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>>


    <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"></android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView>


</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

When I run my app the listview does not appear. The entire screen is black. What I want to know is why this is happening.

Comment: pass your data to `adapter` and supply the `adapter` to the `listview` [HERE](http://www.learnandroidwear.com/sample-1/) you can get idea about the adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the typo in the following line:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>>
```

It cannot read `>>`. Android doesn't throw an exception for this typo

Comment: You have not added any data to the listView. And the BoxInsetLayout height width is wrap_content. So nothing is being rendered. Add a textView with some random text just to test it out