# In the same code, listview appears in activity, but listview does not appear in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

`tried to solve a similar question to mine, but I failed.`

1. [ListView can appear in Activity but can't appear in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780492/listview-can-appear-in-activity-but-cant-appear-in-fragment)
2. [ListView on Fragment does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224791/listview-on-fragment-does-not-appear)

The code that runs in activity does not run in fragment. I tried to resolve it by referring to the article in stackoverflow, but failed Please teach me the way. What the hell is the problem?

**Fragment**

```
public class Fragment_Result extends Fragment {

    EditText et_search;
    ListView lv_search;

    public Fragment_Result() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        lv_search = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_search);
        lv_search.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.add("Adam Smith");
        adapter.add("Bryan Adams");
        adapter.add("Chris Martin");
        adapter.add("Daniel Craig");
        adapter.add("Eric Clapton");
        adapter.add("Frank Sinatra");

        et_search = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_search);
        et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable edit) {
                String filterText = edit.toString();
                if (filterText.length() > 0) {
                    lv_search.setFilterText(filterText);
                } else {
                    lv_search.clearTextFilter();
                }
                ((ArrayAdapter) lv_search.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(filterText);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_search"
        android:text="search : " />

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_search"
        android:id="@+id/et_search"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/et_search"
        android:textFilterEnabled="true"
        android:id="@+id/lv_search"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Only one part of the code used in activity and fragmentation for the title is different.

activity listview : ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

fragment listview : final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the items before setting adapter. Can you try this ?

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    adapter.add("Adam Smith");
    adapter.add("Bryan Adams");
    adapter.add("Chris Martin");
    adapter.add("Daniel Craig");
    adapter.add("Eric Clapton");
    adapter.add("Frank Sinatra");

    lv_search = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_search);
    lv_search.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Even if I change the location of the adapter without final with the code you gave me, the white screen appears as well.